# Google Cast Cocoapods in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, google-cast

Trying to use Google Cast 3.2.0 (via cocoapods) in my Swift project in Xcode, and I get an error when trying to run it in the simulator.

```
Ld /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bingo\ Board.app/Bingo\ Board normal x86_64
    cd /Users/nicholas/OneDrive/Apps/iOS/Bingo2
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.1.sdk -L/Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F\ \"/Users/nicholas/OneDrive/Apps/iOS/Bingo2/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-Public-3.2.0-Release\" -filelist /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Intermediates/Bingo\ Board.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bingo\ Board.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bingo\ Board.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Intermediates/Bingo\ Board.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bingo\ Board.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bingo\ Board_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Intermediates/Bingo\ Board.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bingo\ Board.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bingo_Board.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework GoogleCast -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -ObjC -framework CoreText -framework MediaAccessibility -framework SystemConfiguration -framework GoogleCast -framework StoreKit -lPods-Bingo\ Board -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Intermediates/Bingo\ Board.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bingo\ Board.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Bingo\ Board_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/nicholas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bingo_Board-fqbocunomtcrqobsvzslsuigorec/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bingo\ Board.app/Bingo\ Board

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F "/Users/nicholas/OneDrive/Apps/iOS/Bingo2/Pods/google-cast-sdk/GoogleCastSDK-Public-3.2.0-Release"'
ld: framework not found GoogleCast
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you share your podfile?

Comment: @whammypower788 do you have any swift tutorial to integrate Google cast in iOS ? I am developing video App in iOS Swift 3. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to "pod repo update" then "pod install". If that doesn't work then you need to delete your pod.lock file and start all over with "pod init".